# Composite field in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this model in Rails:

```
class PaymentsDcument < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :domain, :id,  :total, :paid, :paid_left, :percentage
end
```

and I want to add the field  `payment_total = total*percentage`  without creating the field in the database.

Comment: Do you mean make a new Ruby method or use it in a SQL query ?

Comment: I think no SQL query. I want to access that field (payment_total) in my view. And change value automatic when total or percentage in changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people use a Presenter for this kind of code, but you could go with

```
class PaymentsDcument < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :domain, :id,  :total, :paid, :paid_left, :percentage

  def payment_total
    total*percentage
  end
end
```